# Deleting duplicates only if they are a certain kind of duplicate

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
{{1,a,b},{1,1,b},{1,a,a},{b,a,1},{b,a,b}}
```

I would like to find a way to delete all those tuples in the list that contain a duplicate unless that duplicate is a `1`. Therefore, the desired result given the example input above would be:

```
{{1,a,b},{1,1,b},{b,a,1}}
```

I will also need to delete duplicate elements within the list (irrespective of sorting) but that is easily done (i.e. only keep one of `{1,a,b}` and `{b,a,1}`).

I would like it to work for generic length tuples too, for example:

```
{{1,1,1,1},{1,a,a,b},{a,b,b,c},{1,a,b,c},{1,1,a,b}}
```

would become

```
{{1,1,1,1},{1,a,b,c},{1,1,a,b}}
```

Comment: Before I clicked into the post I thought it was a meta question (from the title) :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
list = {{1, a, b}, {1, 1, b}, {1, a, a}, {b, a, 1}, {b, a, b}};
l1 = Select[list,DuplicateFreeQ[DeleteCases[#,1]]&]
```

> {{1, a, b}, {1, 1, b}, {b, a, 1}}

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@l1
```

> {{1, a, b}, {1, 1, b}}

```
list2 = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, a, a, b}, {a, b, b, c}, {1, a, b, c}, {1,  1, a, b}};
l2 = Select[list2, DuplicateFreeQ[DeleteCases[#, 1]] &]
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, a, b, c}, {1, 1, a, b}}

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@l2
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, a, b, c}, {1, 1, a, b}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, a, b}, {1, 1, b}, {1, a, a}, {b, a, 1}, {b, a, b}};
```

Using `OrderlessPatternSequence`

```
DeleteCases[list, {OrderlessPatternSequence[a_, a_, _] /; a =!= 1}]
```

{{1, a, b}, {1, 1, b}, {b, a, 1}}

```
list = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, a, a, b}, {a, b, b, c}, {1, a, b, c}, {1, 1, a, b}};

DeleteCases[list, {OrderlessPatternSequence[a_, a_, __] /; a =!= 1}]
```

{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, a, b, c}, {1, 1, a, b}}

Answer (score 1):

This defines a function which deletes duplicates while ignoring the duplicates of given parameters:

```
ClearAll[deleteDuplicates];
deleteDuplicates[a__] := Pick[#, 
    SameQ[#, DeleteDuplicates[#, 
       Apply[And, Join[{SameQ[#1, #2]}, 
         Function[temp, UnsameQ[temp, #1]] /@ {a}]
       ]& ]
    ] & /@ #] &;
```

For example:

> deleteDuplicates[1][{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}]
>
> deleteDuplicates[2][{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}]
>
> deleteDuplicates[1, 2][{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}]

gives

> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}}
>
> {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}}
>
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{1, a, b}, {1, 1, b}, {1, a, a}, {b, a, 1}, {b, a, b}};
```

Using `Cases` and `DeleteElements`:

```
patt = Cases[#, s : {__Symbol, _} | {_, __Symbol} /; ! DuplicateFreeQ[s]] &;

DeleteElements[#, patt@#] &@list

(*{{1, a, b}, {1, 1, b}, {b, a, 1}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Tally`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];

list = {{1, a, b}, {1, 1, b}, {1, a, a}, {b, a, 1}, {b, a, b}, {1, 1, 
    1}, {a, 1, b, c, 1}};
picker = Tally /@ list /. {_, 1} :> Nothing /. {1, _} :> Nothing // 
   Map[Length];
Pick[list, picker, 0]
```

---

> {{1, a, b}, {1, 1, b}, {b, a, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {a, 1, b, c, 1}}

---

From the `Tally` output, every tally that is not a duplicate is deleted and then every pair where `1` is counted any number of times is deleted. Anything that is left represents represents a duplicate other than `1`. A `0` output from the picker means no duplicates except for `1` and only such sublists are picked up.